# ORA-24344: success with compilation error. Trigger apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a trigger in oracle apex which will select all the data that i have in the UniversityRefNo column and not allow the user to put in an already existing value. However, i keep getting this error: `"ORA-24344: success with compilation error."` if anyone could tell me what im doing wrong that would be great.

```
CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEER(
Volunteer_id         NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,    
Title                VARCHAR2(5),    
VolName              VARCHAR2(30),   
UniversityRefNo      VARCHAR2(10),    
Address_Line_1       VARCHAR2(30),   
Address_Line_2       VARCHAR2(12),    
PostCode             VARCHAR2(12),    
Mobile_Number        NUMBER(12),    
Home_Number          NUMBER(12),    
Email                VARCHAR2(25),    
Ethnic_Group         VARCHAR2(10),    
VolunteerType        VARCHAR2(10),   
Register_Disable     VARCHAR2(3),  
Gender               VARCHAR2(1),  
Medical_Details      VARCHAR2(20),   
PassPortNumber       NUMBER(10),   
Nationality          VARCHAR2(10),   
Passport_Expiry_Date DATE,    
Date_of_Birth        DATE,   
Course_Name          VARCHAR2(20),   
Course_Year          VARCHAR2(10),   
Area_of_work         VARCHAR2(15),    
StaffManagerName     VARCHAR2(20),    
StaffManagerEmail    VARCHAR2(20),    
StaffManagerPhone    VARCHAR2(12));   

CREATE or replace trigger unirefnoTrigger    
before insert or update of UniversityRefNo ON VOLUNTEER for each row    
begin    
SELECT UniversityRefNo from VOLUNTEER    
if(UniversityRefno = :new.UniversityRefNo) then raise application error(UniversityRefNO || :new.UniversityRefNo || 'already exists');   
end if;    
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the column UniversityRefNo unique you don't need to make a trigger you can simple create a Unique Constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE VOLUNTEER 
ADD CONSTRAINT UniversityRefNo_UK UNIQUE (UniversityRefNo);
```

Just for learning purposes below is how you can create a trigger to do the same thing but I do NOT recommend you use it.

```
CREATE or replace trigger unirefnoTrigger
before insert or update of UniversityRefNo ON VOLUNTEER for each row
university_count number;
begin
SELECT count(*) into university_count from VOLUNTEER where UniversityRefno=:new.UniversityRefNo;
if university_count<>0 then 
raise application error(-20000, :new.UniversityRefNo || ' already exists');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: I think the OP intention is to give the end user a more descriptive error message than the "ORA-00001: unique constraint (constraint_name) violated", but yes, there are better ways to do this.